# display product tags on product page above tag form?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display product tags above tags form for all users on product page and category page also.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742046/how-to-get-only-the-tags-of-a-product-in-view-phtml-in-magento-1-7-0-2

Comment: this is not working, I have tested this code in  product/view.phtml  and   tag/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Add this code :

```
<?php $tagCollection = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->getResourceCollection()
                     ->addPopularity()
                     ->load();
 foreach($tagCollection as $tag): ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();?>"><?php echo $tag->getName();?></a>
        <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

- in template product category and product view ex: template\catalog\product\view.phtml 
pls add this code to call this anywhere that you want

Example: i add above form

```
 <div class="product-essential">
  <?php $tagCollection = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->getResourceCollection()
                     ->addPopularity()
                     ->load();
 foreach($tagCollection as $tag): ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();?>"><?php echo $tag->getName();?></a>
        <?php endforeach;  ?>

  <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
<?php
                $tagmodel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
                $collection = $tagmodel->getResourceCollection()
                                            ->addPopularity()
                                            ->load();
                foreach($collection as $tag){ ?>
                     <a href="<?php echo $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();?>"><?php echo $tag->getName();?></a>
            <?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
  $TaGCollection= $model->getResourceCollection()
            ->addPopularity()
            ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
            ->addProductFilter($ProductId)
            ->setFlag('relation', true)
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setActiveFilter()
            ->load();

use below to fetch

$Tags=$TaGCollection->getItems();

 if(count($Tags)):
   foreach ($Tags as $tag) {
           echo  $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();
    echo $tag->getName();

    }
 endif;
```